# cardBackgroundColor and cardCornerRadius not working in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-cardview, androidx

I'm struggling with CardView corner radius and background color with AndroidX libraries.

I've defined my layout as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/retail_card_width"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/baseYellow"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/retail_card_height">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   tools:src="@drawable/ic_fruit_1"
                   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRetailBrand"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/brand_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/brand_icon_size"
                tools:src="@drawable/esselunga"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/retail_brand_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/retail_brand_margin"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Unfortunately, neither `cardCornerRadius` nor `cardBackgroundColor` seem working on my layout. I can't understand if my issue depends on AndroidX libraries or not.

Here there's my layout preview:

[image: cardview issue]

Comment: I tried above cannot reproduce the same issue. I just migrated my Demo Project to AndroidX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was I was mixing cardview androidx library with support recyclerview library. Once I rebuilt the project with:

```xml
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

everything turned out fine.

Comment: it's still same

Answer (score 6):

I removed this lines in my Manifest file and after that my cardviews are worked prefectly fine

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Answer (score 4):

Try modifying the CardView as:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/retail_card_width"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/baseYellow"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/retail_card_height">
```

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi which androidx version you are on ?

Comment: androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0

Comment: Did you try on actual device? It may be caching error which will clear once you run.

Answer (score 3):

I might be late for this but let me save someone's time in the future. I had this problem on my `Android Studio preview` and came to realise that the problem  is that the content inside the CardView is not `clipped` to the bounds of the CardView, so the corners you see are corners of the ImageView, which is actually clipped when you run the app on emulator/device.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by wrapping the CardView in FrameLayout.

**Addition to an answer:**

Or you can try using "app" namespace instead of "card_view":

```
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_color"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius"
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to the CardView setup.

Check Your ImageView they can be the reason for corner's not being rounded.

Comment Out Image View Code(whole ConstraintLayout) and check the UI.As i had the Same Issue in Past.

Comment: you are right, without ```ImageView``` code is working fine. but how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

try to clean and rebuild the project. This worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I ran into the same issue, and none of these suggestions resolved my issue. I was setting the background color of the card via cardview.setBackgroundColor(color):
[image]
, instead of cardview.set**Card**BackgroundColor()
[image]
. The cardview contains an embedded object, of card, the card is where the corner radius is appended to. So setting the color outside of the CardView.Card will not render the corner-radius as intended. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new drawable file round_corner_colored.xml and paste the following code in that file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid
    android:color="@color/light_sky_blue"/>

<corners
    android:radius="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

</shape>
```

Now set this drawable the background of cardview as :

```
 android:background="@drawable/round_corner_colored"
```

Hope it will help !!

Answer (score 0):

There are brands that force `Dark mode` when app installed for the first time this will affect the coloration of views and applying color in CardView will get ignored. You may apply this to your main theme to prevent such event.

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, It wasn't showing properly in Preview. But it was showing properly on the device. There is some rendering issue. I keep encountering such problems in android studio.

Faced issue in  Android Studio 4.2.1 (Mac)

Comment: Hi Darshn - did you got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/low"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I upgraded **compileSdkVersion** from 28 to 29 in app level gradle and the problem solved.

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```