# cardCornerRadius not working in androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

Tags: android, android-cardview, cornerradius

**i am using cardview to creat meu in m first app and here i want rounded corner but not working with the following codes in androidx cardview ?**

i am new here also please guide if anything !
please advice !
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="co.csons.tech.erms.menu">

<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/bellcon"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"/>

             </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cardBackgroundColor and cardCornerRadius not working in AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835962/cardbackgroundcolor-and-cardcornerradius-not-working-in-androidx)

Answer (score 1):

add this line in cardview xml

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Hopefully it will solve issue.

Comment: check answer. Thanks